# Multiplayer minecraft on one PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to run two instances of Minecraft and have two players on the same world on the same PC with no internet connection? Does anyone know how this could be done. I have tried to run Minecraft twice but there was just one player not two.

Comment: @pppery The two questions don't seem to be asking about the same thing to me. This one is about playing on a single computer, while the other is about playing on a single account (not necessarily a single computer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mod called [Joypad mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1283271-joypad-mod-usb-controller-split-screen-over-74k) This allows you to play splitscreen upto version 1.7.10. With one person using keyboard and one person using a controller.

[image]

This is the only method i know of that works as you need a controller mod anyway as you cannot have two keyboards plugged in working for seperate programs.

I use this with friends when they are round and we want to play on a big screen.

Hope this helps

**Sidenote**
You can run minecraft twice but it requires two minecraft account. I do this to record time lapses using cam studio mod. The way that i run two instances is to open the launcher normally then right click and run as administrator. If can do this with just one account if you dont want to connect them together say two friends playing seperate worlds, but you cant do this multiplayer or even playing over lan as the game will error saying a player with that name is already on the server.

Comment: How well does this work regarding LAN? Can Minecraft see clients running on the same PC as LAN worlds?

Comment: you do play over a lan world. i have done this with 4 players in total on 2 computers. so it does work but i always feel bad for the people using keyboards. also this works with two monitors quite well so each person has a monitor @Studoku

Comment: @Studoku it runs as multiple instances of the game so it runs as well as your computer can handle it and can run as many instances as you like. so each screen is its own independent game.